# How to get notified (run script) on every SSH connection?

Tags: server, ssh, scripts, sshd

I'm able to run a script automatically every time I log into my machine via SSH by placing a command in the `/etc/ssh/sshrc` file. That works perfectly, however it's only triggered when I log in via terminal or SFTP file browser like [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/).

It *does not* run my script when I connect to a MySQL or MongoDB instance over SSH (where the database host is `localhost` through an SSH tunnel, see below).

How can I ensure this script gets run on every SSH connection to the server?

[image]

Comment: So you mean every time you get a new connection established over an already existing ssh tunnel?

Comment: What is the screenshot from?

Comment: No these are new tunnels, not existing ones. Screenshot is from Sequel Pro, MySQL browser. http://www.sequelpro.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways:

- use a [`~/.ssh/rc`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Client_Configuration_Files#.7E.2F.ssh.2Frc) script;
- use the **ForceCommand** keyword in [`sshd.conf`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5?query=sshd_config) telling `sshd` to execute a command on every login (but this will also make `sshd` ignore any command supplied by the client and `~/.ssh/rc` if present).
- monitor `/var/log/auth` using a tool like [logwatch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Logwatch).

I assume using a `rc` script is the easiest solution.

Comment: Options 1 and 2 did not work. My script is run when I log in via terminal, but not MongoDB/MySQL ssh tunnel.